# Vk api реализация загрузки фото в личное сообщение

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Приложение проходит авторизацию. Далее хочу загрузить имеющееся в проекте фото в личное сообщение. Вот написано как это делать https://vk.com/dev/upload_files. Я не то чтобы не смог написать, я даже не понял как писать этот кусочек кода, куда сохранится адрес для загрузки фото, как указать загрузку в него фото, да еще в нужный мне диалог. Я даже примерный код не могу сообразить. Вот единственное что нашел http://www.cyberforum.ru/java/thread967273.html.

Вот например код для отправки фото на стену

```
case R.id.upload_photo_to_wall: {
     final Bitmap photo = getPhoto();
     VKRequest request = VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(new VKUploadImage(photo, VKImageParameters.jpgImage(0.9f)), 0, TARGET_GROUP);
     request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
         recycleBitmap(photo);
         VKApiPhoto photoModel = ((VKPhotoArray) response.parsedModel).get(0);
         makePost(new VKAttachments(photoModel));
     }
```

Помогите разобраться с задачей.

Comment: Советую внимательно прочитать этот кусок документации -- http://vk.cc/3PDOV4

Comment: первая ссылка в моем вопросе и есть ссылка на эту документацию. я не могу эти три шага реализовать. да вообще первый шаг хотя бы , получить адрес для загрузки

Comment: допустим хочу выполнить первый шаг описанный в документации. написано метод photos.getMessagesUploadServer возвращает адрес для загрузки. как мне получить этот адрес ? хочу например сохранить его в строковую переменную. Как сделать запрос на сервер и сохранить ответ в строку ?

Comment: Если вы задаёте такие вопросы, то вам еще рано заниматься таким. Изучите основы работы с сетью, а потом пробуйте решить свой вопрос.

Comment: согласен, я еще очень мало знаю, но так получилось , что я уже взял за реализацию одной идеи и хотел бы её добить, очень многое уже сделано, практически не понимая как это работает и остался последний шаг. А после уже конечно же продолжу разбирать основы. Раз мне и гугл не отвечает на вопрос " как сохранить ответ от сервера" значит я как то не правильно его формулирую, хотя я уже много вариантов перепробовал.